# Mantra to attract a specific woman

Tags: mantras, women, love

Basically I need a love mantra directed at a single person. Does one exist? I tried looking for one but could never confirm if it was actually a love mantra.

Comment: oh brother, I wonder why you're asking this in public forums like these, you can't just chant the mantra and expect it to work, there has to be resonance in your spiritual self, your speech and your mental ability for _any_ mantra to work. C'mon anyone could misuse a mantra if it was not so. But, I think people who can do that, .... wouldn't misuse it for meager things, since they are supposed to be spiritually aware

Comment: There are many. You can search a site called Prophet666

Comment: The conscious seeking of `kaamam` and the chanting of `mantram` must not go together. If you believe in things like `kuttichaathan` or black magic, you may consult scholars on that topic instead. I believe such rituals exist among them.

Answer (score 1):

A charm about this is given in atharvaved.

- Atharvaved 6:8

> “1. Like as the creeper throws, her arms on every side around the tree, So hold you me in your embrace that you may be in love with me, my darling, never to depart. 2. As, when he mounts, the eagle strikes his pinions downward on the earth, So do I strike your spirit down that you may be in love with me, my darling, never to depart. 3. As round this heaven and earth, the sun, goes day by day, encircling them, So do I compass round your mind that you may be in love with me, my darling, never to depart.”

[image]

Comment: How many times are you suppose to apply this? Can you use the English version or do you need to use the hindi version? When and where are you suppose to speak this mantra out loud?

Comment: @Wikash_ it is not a part of question.

Comment: @Wikash_ I translated the verse in English.

Comment: @Wikash_ -  Why will it not work ? There might be other pre-reqs which a traditional acharya or other scripture can elaborate . But that is not what OP has asked

Comment: This is called the "kaamaatma suktam" and is said to have been written down by `Jamadaagni muni`.

Comment: @AravindSuresh I know this